Filter PowerApps ComboBox options based on another column in a different SP List
I have two SharePoint lists, Maintenance Work Orders and Machines. In my Canvas App, I have a combobox that is used to fill in the machine number in the Machine_Number column of the Maintenance Work Orders list. However, I only want the options in this combobox to be machine numbers which have the Active column of the Machines list set to true
I've tried setting the Items property of the combobox to
Distinct(
  Filter(
    'Machines',
    Active = true
  ),
  Title
)

and the Update property of the data card to
combobox.Selected

which correctly filters the list of available machine numbers, however, when the work order is saved, the machine number column is left blank (even though it is set to not allow blanks"
I've also tried setting the Items property of the combobox to
Filter(
    Choices([@'Maintenance Work Orders'].Machine_Number), 
    Value in LookUp('Machines', Title = Value, Active = true)
)

However this doesn't populate any options in the combobox at run-time.
